Redirect with token after Authentication
I am creating simple webapp with authentication in spring boot using JWT. fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/auth'... This return correctly token. Then I can use:
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/admin', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token // Użycie tokena
        }
    })

After this everything is ok, but I want redirect to  'http://localhost:8080/api/admin'.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form id="loginForm">
        <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    <p id="error-message" style="color: red;"></p>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); 

            const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
            const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

            fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/auth', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }
            })
            .then(data => {
                const token = data.token; 
                localStorage.setItem('jwttoken', token);
                // ...
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('There has been a problem with your fetch operation:', error);
                document.getElementById('error-message').innerText = 'Invalid username or password';
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>

I have no idea, how make redirect after saving token in localStorage. I need to have in header:
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token

It appears that redirects with header information using scripts is not viable - see here link to header debate on Stackoverflow
There appears to be some debate about whether it is possible, but from my understanding of email protocols it is possible to headers in PHP, but maybe not for a redirect as they say.
An alternative could be to encrypt the token data in a URL parameter, eg.
window.location.href = "http://www.target.com?token=aef654898ab";
I see your issue is more complicated though as you are attempting to write JSON header data to the API. I'm not sure this is possible as you are simply writing it to a key called 'Header' in the JSON array, and I don't think this would have any effect on the actual page header.
Therefore, it may or may not be the right way to go about it for your authentication purpose.
You may wish to look at the open-source OAuth site for guidance here - link to OAuth site
Also, I'm uncertain about the order of your javascript - wouldn't you want to set your token before you process your fetch operation?
